# Feature Request: Omit links from expanded usercard

Tags: feature-request

I have profile text that renders like this

> To me, software and data are [nature's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dwTsyiHu) most interesting systems.

and an expanded usercard that renders like this

[image]

They come from this markdown

```
To me, software and data are [nature's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dwTsyiHu) most interesting systems.

<!-- summary: Hi!  You hovered over my name!  Stay curious!  :) -->
```

---

However, I do not want the link at the bottom:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the link is a result of [documented, expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> Your expanded usercard will show the following information:
>
> ...
>
> - Any additional HTML links will be displayed and linked at the
>     bottom of the expanded usercard. This does not repeat any links that
>     are already shown in the previous part.

Hence, the link is being shown at the bottom of the usercard because my `<!-- summary: -->` doesn't include it.  **I would like some way to omit the link.**

Comment: TIL that the summary comment is a thing.